# PayPal IPN values are being received in the thank you page rather than IPN page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I see PayPal hits the ipn.php however, I'm unable to see/catch any data through $_REQUEST or $_POST. From this post-[Not receiving any IPN post for sandbox account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805264/not-receiving-any-ipn-post-for-sandbox-account) I see I need to enable the IPN but I'm unable to locate it.

This is my PHP code

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO dumped (dumped)
    VALUES (".$_REQUEST.")");
```

But when I enter the below code I see data is inserted into DB Table.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO dumped (dumped)
    VALUES ('blablabla')");
```

Below is the form which submitted:

```
define( 'SSL_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );
            define( 'SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );

            $action = '';
            //Is this a test transaction? 
            $action = ($data['paypal_mode']) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_URL;

            $form = '';

            $form .= '<form name="frm_payment_method" action="' . $action . '" method="post">';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . $data['merchant_email'] . '" />';
            // Instant Payment Notification & Return Page Details /
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="' . $data['notify_url'] . '" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' . $data['cancel_url'] . '" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $data['thanks_page'] . '" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />';
            // Configures Basic Checkout Fields -->
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="" />';
            /*$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />';*/
            // <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="localhost" />-->
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $data['currency_code'] . '" />';
            //$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="paypal" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $data['product_name'] . '" />';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd"/>';
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $data['amount'] . '" />';

            $form .= '</form>';
            $form .= '<script>';
            $form .= 'setTimeout("document.frm_payment_method.submit()", 0);';
            $form .= '</script>';
            return $form;
```

The values I'm receiving in the thank you page looks like;

```
Array ( [payer_email] => niladrib.banerjee@XXXX [payer_id] => WN6EJUKG27CZ8 [payer_status] => VERIFIED [first_name] => Niladri [last_name] => Banerjee [address_name] => Niladri Banerjee [address_street] => 1 Main St [address_city] => San Jose [address_state] => CA [address_country_code] => US [address_zip] => 95131 [residence_country] => US [txn_id] => XXX [mc_currency] => USD [mc_fee] => 0.46 [mc_gross] => 5.50 [protection_eligibility] => ELIGIBLE [payment_fee] => 0.46 [payment_gross] => 5.50 [payment_status] => Completed [payment_type] => instant [item_name] => Demo Product [quantity] => 1 [txn_type] => web_accept [payment_date] => 2018-11-15T12:02:01Z [business] => niladrib.banerjee-facilitator@XXXXX [receiver_id] => 9K4AYW8P9K555 [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED [verify_sign] => Au.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX )
```

Comment: Is there a `My selling tools` menu in your dashboard?
Under `Profile` you can have access to the `Instant payment notifications` sector

Comment: @DiogoSanto I have found the expected thing from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?dispatch=XXXXXX, however, post values are being received in the thank you page rather than ipn.php. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm is the `Auto Return` option selected in your paypal dashboard?
Also, when you send the request to paypal how many possible redirects did you set for each possible scenario? You can set up more than one redirection depending of the paypal answer. You tell them where you wish them to redirect the answer for the many cases and they will pick it up depending of what happened in their system.
But I would start by making sure the dashboard is all set up for the process :) Can you confirm the `Auto Return` selection?

Comment: @DiogoSanto I've updated my question. can you please check?

Comment: @DiogoSanto Sorry, can't see any `Auto Return` section from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Comment: Thank you for updating it! :) I am analising this now.
Meanwhile, what I referenced is located at `My account -> Overview -> Website preferences -> update` can you confirm if `Auto return` is in there and selected, please? :)

Comment: @DiogoSanto I see `Auto Return` is `Off`

Comment: Can you turn it `ON` and confirm in your `My Account -> Profile -> My Selling Tools` select `Update` and choose `IPN Settings`? Confirm you have set up a specific URL redirection in there for your `IPN.php` file.

You are looking for `Notification URL` text box

Comment: @DiogoSanto already done

Comment: @DiogoSanto already entered the notification url and saved with Receive IPN messages (Enabled)

Comment: Hmmm and no data provided at all in their request?

Comment: yes, no data in notify_url (e.g. $_POST or $_REQUEST) but received the data in the thank you page ("return") through print_r($_POST);

Comment: Just for giggles, can you remove the notify_url parameter from your form and try again?

Comment: Nothing happen, It still shows the values in thank you page. Also, the record which contains 'blablabla' as stated in my question has stopped storing into the db table.

Comment: Apologies @Niladri I am running out of ideas here :x 
Although I detected something similar to your case already in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795985/post-from-paypal-response-after-payment-is-empty).

Comment: @DiogoSanto No issue.